# Filtering out duplicate values does not work via JPA

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm having the following database model. A software `package` has multiple `versions`. Each version has a `license`.

Here are the SQL scripts.

Create the `license` table.

```sql
create table license (
    id int primary key generated always as identity,
    name text not null
);
```

Create the `package` table.

```sql
create table package (
    id int primary key generated always as identity,
    name text not null
);
```

Create the `version` table.

```
create table version (
    id int primary key generated always as identity,
    pkg_id int not null references package,
    license_id int references license,
    version text not null
);
```

I'm using Spring Boot and here are my entities.

First the `License.java`.

```java
@Entity
public class License {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "license", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Version> versions = new HashSet<>();

  // ...

}
```

Then the `Package.java`.

```
@Entity
public class Package {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pkg", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Version> versions = new HashSet<>();

  // ...
}
```

And finally the `Version.java`.

```java
@Entity
public class Version {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String version;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Package pkg;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private License license;

  // ...
}
```

Now I'd like to find all packages that have a certain license, e.g. `MIT`. Strictly speaking that means, find all versions where the license is equals `MIT` and return the packages removing duplicate ones.

Here is my first approach.

```java
@Repository
public interface PackageRepository extends JpaRepository<Package, Integer> {

  @Query(value = "select p from Package p join p.versions v where v.license.name = :name")
  Page<Package> findByLicenseName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

However that returns duplicate packages because a package might have multiple versions that all have the `MIT` license.

That's why I've tried another approach. Notice the extra `distinct` keyword.

```java
  @Query(value = "select distinct p from Package p join p.versions v where v.license.name = :name")
  Page<Package> findByLicenseName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

That generates the following SQL query.

```sql
    select
        distinct package0_.id as id1_1_,
        package0_.name as name2_1_ 
    from
        package package0_ 
    inner join
        version versions1_ 
            on package0_.id=versions1_.pkg_id cross 
    join
        license license2_ 
    where
        versions1_.license_id=license2_.id 
        and license2_.name=? limit ?
```

And it works \o/. My problem is that I have a huge database with millions of rows. Adding distinct to the SQL query takes minutes before I see any results.

Then I thought I could simply filter out duplicates in my Java code.

```java
  public Page<NpmPackageRecord> findByLicenseId(
      @RequestParam("license-id") String licenseId, Pageable pageable) {
    // get packages including duplicates from database
    var packages = npmPackageVersionRepository.findByLicenseId(licenseId, pageable);

    // filter out duplicates
    return new PageImpl<>(
        packages.getContent().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()),
        pageable,
        packages.getTotalElements());
  }
```

That also works but then I have the problem that my content does not match what is inside the `Pageable`.

So I did some research and found a fourth solution. Adding `distinct` to the query but leave it to Hibernate to filter out duplicates.

```java
  @QueryHints(
      value = {
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false"),
      })
  @Query(value = "select distinct p from Package p join p.versions v where v.license.name = :name")
  Page<Package> findByLicenseName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

This generates the SQL query.

```sql
    select
        package0_.id as id1_1_,
        package0_.name as name2_1_ 
    from
        package package0_ 
    inner join
        version versions1_ 
            on package0_.id=versions1_.pkg_id cross 
    join
        license license2_ 
    where
        versions1_.license_id=license2_.id 
        and license2_.name=? limit ?
```

That looks promising as the `distinct` keyword is not passed to the database. However I'm seeing duplicate values.

Here is a demo project that you can use to play around.

https://github.com/zemirco/jpa-distinct-demo

Now I'm lost. Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is titled wrong - distinct does work, you just don't like the performance impact it has. You are stuck by the pagination requirement. Either use distinct to get pagination to be respected, or go a different route and write your own querying/filtering/pagination mechanism to do it in memory - but risk the wasted effort as it will likely perform similarly, just locally. Another approach might be to get a PostgreSQL DBA to chime in on your table and how to make that query with the distinct run quicker or over less data, but you might want to break that into a separate question.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Do you want to make it a proper answer? I would accept it.